# changed password is not updated for chroot-ed environment

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, password-management, chroot

I have a RHEL box or development. I changed my user and root passwords on it and I can see the change in effect. However, I have a chroot environment on this box and the changed passwords do not work for this environment. I have to use my old passwords. Do I need to chroot into this environment and change passwords there as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "chroot" is a separate system (sharing only the kernel). It has its own `etc/shadow` with its own passwords. So yes, you need to change them twice, inside and outside the chroot.

Comment: I could this figure out using my psychic abilities but need some one to verify it :-)